# Is there a tree with a fixed height?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a tree that once grown (from sapling to tree) it has always a X height and remain that amount forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No trees grow after their initial transformation from sapling to tree. You can limit the height of oak trees by building a ceiling (so that large trees don't grow). The height of the trunk will still vary though.

The most uniform type of trees are [birch trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Birch_Trees):

> The trunk will grow to be 5, 6, or 7 blocks tall.

Spruce and jungle trees vary wildly and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

No need to build a ceiling. Just dig a 1 block hole, plant a sapling in it and use bonemeal, you will never get large trees with this method. Placing 4 blocks around the sapling also works:

```
 X 
XSX
 X

X = Dirt 
S = Sapling
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Yes, you will never get a large tree, but small trees' heights vary from 5-7 blocks.

Comment: I am sorry, I just tested that and it is not true. I even got a large tree with this method.

Comment: Really ? They must have updated this. Or maybe it's 2 block hole. @fredley (I learn a lot from you haha ^^)